If I'm turning humans into crude oil, would removing their skeletons accelerate this process?
The Chthonic Hivemind is currently terraforming a barren Earth into a corpse world for it to live in. It intends to fill the empty oceans with crude oil made from countless human corpses to form the Oil Oceans. It wants to mimic the process of actual crude oil formation. It removes the skeletons from the corpses for a different terraforming project.
Would removing the skeletons accelerate the formation of crude oil?

I know you said "countless", but I still must point out that it would take quintillions of human corpses to fill the oceans to anywhere near their current depth.

The sum total of the mass of all the humans who have ever lived on Earth is not even one billionth of the mass of the ocean. The ocean is biggg.

That's not a valid close reason as far as I'm aware, and the judgment of what's ugly would seem to be highly subjective - whereas we usually close for reasons that can be defined objectivley. If you feel otherwise, then perhaps consider posting the issue on worldbuilding meta. @GraySheep

@AlexP I think that if we’re talking about an entity that is terraforming an entire planet into a corpse world that it, ostensibly a single organism/hivemind in this case, can use as something so theoretically-compact as a house, then it probably also has access to functionally-unlimited humans who are adequately-dead to be used to produce oil.

@GraySheep Good worldbuilding can have some very ugly things in it.  It's not all unicorns and rainbows.  Good stories need to have problems to overcome.  Look at IRL history, people have done worse things than this.  Please tread carefully around making such value judgements upon questions.

@GraySheep As the saying goes, a woman's trash is another woman's treasure.

@GraySheep And as you were told for the sugar processing question: not a valid reason to downvote a question. This question is not really all that different than War of the Worlds in which people were ground up and sprayed onto alien flora as fertilizer as part of an alien terraforming project.  It was an important worldbuilding choice for the whole story because H. G. Wells realized that the aliens could just co-exist with us inferior animals the same way that humans co-exist with monkeys.

But he needed a reason for the aliens to want to hunt down and destroy humanity for his story to work; so, turning people into a useful resource was a logical choice.  So, either you think H. G. Wells is a shitty worldbuilder (which I hope we can all agree is not true), or you are getting caught up on the details of these questions because you do not understand their role in the stories they are meant to tell.

It is unlikely that removing the skeletons would either help or hinder petroleum formation.  Human bones are primarily Calcium compounds in an organic matrix, and calcium compounds don't really take part in the formation of petroleum, they would merely form the inevitable inorganic compounds mixed with the petroleum.
It might seem that the bones would prevent compaction of the corpses, but with a sufficient mass of bodies, the flesh would compact around the bones, and any bones that were in a position to prevent compaction would do so only briefly before they either bend or break to allow compaction to continue.

Mandatory XKCD reference: https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/

Is it possible that some components, or degradation products, of bone could act as catalysts to speed up (or slow down!) the process of petroleum formation?

The chthonic hivemind might make a polite request to "Changing World Technologies" - a real-life company operating a plant that turns turkey processing (and other biological) waste into something similar to crude oil, in what they say is an accelerated process similar to how it happens naturally.
In the interview I remembered (and found again) they talk about taking the bones too, but also about selling/using "byproducts" - so it would seem like the bones don't hinder the process enough to worry about removing them, but if as Monty Wild states they don't contribute to the process, what's left of them will be left behind. Possibly making the ocean floors a bit higher than they currently are.
